# Bitbucket pipeline - assign custom variables

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I would like to assign custom variables using bash commands

```html
image: alpine

pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: docker-login
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - docker login --username $DOCKER_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_PASSWORD
            - echo "logged in to docker hub"
            - echo $VERSION
          variables:
            VERSION: cat ./version.txt
      - step: 
          name: build-image
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - echo "running docker image test"
      - step:
          name: 'set ssh env'
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0
              variables:
                SSH_USER: $SSH_USER
                SERVER: '$HOST'
                COMMAND: 'pwd'
```

I am not getting the output of the file.. what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Can you paste your whole yaml file? are you running a custom pipeline?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun edited the post, no default pipelines

Comment: I'm writing the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your base image that step is running on doesn't support to set environment variables externally. you can not create variables like that. For example, your pipe image `atlassian/ssh-run:0.4.0` has these environment variables set, so you can define. But `docker-login` step will be using `image: alpine` for its base and this base image doesn't have this environment variables set to be configured. There are three types of variables in Bitbucket (workspace variables, repository variables and deployment variables.) none of them meets your need in this use case. Because all these variable types are static and working as key/value.

We can try something else like below ;

```
image: alpine

pipelines:
  default:
      - step:
          name: docker-login
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - docker login --username $DOCKER_USERNAME --password $DOCKER_PASSWORD
            - echo "logged in to docker hub"
            - export VERSION=$(cat ./version.txt)
            - echo $VERSION
```

Creating variables with linux commands will be helpful here. Also, pls keep in mind that these type of variables (in this case `$VERSION` variable) will only be identified in its step. If you want to carry it to other steps, you should use artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

"Setup environment variables in bitbucket-pipelines.yml" is currently an open suggestion gathering interest on Bitbucket Cloud: [BCLOUD-17453](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-17453)

Comment: Its now September and it still "gathers interest" - and is still .. open :(